# Вытащить данные из объекта

Tags: php, объекты

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно вывести данные из объекта php
объект имеет вот такой вид:

```
stdClass Object ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [name] => Insert 
    [value] => 5
    [year] => 2001 
  ) 
  [1] => stdClass Object ( 
    [name] => Delet
    [value] => 6
    [year] => 2001 
  ) 
)
```

Каким образом правильно вывести данные из [0][name] ?
я не нашел в гугле как работать с числовыми ключами в объектах и вот такой выод у меня не получается

```
echo $obj->0->name;
```

выдает ошибку, подскажите что я делаю не так?

Comment: Так работает `$obj[0]->name`?

Comment: @gil9red не получается( пишет ошибку " Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно будет числовой индекс заключить в фигурные скобки:

```
echo $obj->{0}->name;
```

Comment: спасибо сработало) если конвертируете в ответ то помечу галкой

Comment: @dantelol это и есть ответ О_о

Comment: @dantelol ну что там по галочке?))